# ftp file download working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: c#, ftp, download

```
string HostName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HostName"];
string strUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BasicAuthenticationUser"];
string strPWD = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BasicAuthenticationPWD"];

strFile = "9788191073072.zip";

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HostName + strFile);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUser, strPWD);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[2 * 1024];
int read;

while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) { Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read); }

responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: You need to specify what exactly isn't working? What exception is being thrown if any? You also seem to be missing variable type for strFile on fourth line.

Comment: my code is working fine on local system. but on sever after published website my code is not working. no exception no error file is not downloading

Comment: have you tried tracing details with Fiddler when requesting from server? perhaps there is a clue in the raw response stream. server event log may have some clue as well.

Comment: thanks Maverik now my code is working :)

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps it would help others if you could post in the answer (and mark your answer as "the answer") what exactly was going wrong for you and how you fixed it so others can benefit in future.

Comment: using the same above code  now iam trying to download any size of Zip file having some MP3 files. when download completed i dont know why the mp3 files are damaged every time

Answer (score 1):

```
string HostName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HostName"];
string strUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BasicAuthenticationUser"];
string strPWD = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BasicAuthenticationPWD"];

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HostName + strFile);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUser, strPWD);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + _AudiobookName + ".zip");
int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[2 * 1024];
while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    Response.Flush();
}
responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: you can add this to your question instead, if it is supposed to be an edit to the question

Comment: No, i think it is the answer. I notice he has added stream flushing & content type to the code now. Hopefully this can help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Without any real detail to go on, this could have to do Mime types setup on production server.

This can also be possibly due to transparent proxy filtering policies that may exist between you and the server.

Again, you really should do a fine grained trace through Fiddler to see what really is being returned by server and if the requests are finishing successfully.

Assuming this is an IIS server, a look in server event logs can also tell you if application pool is crashing and getting restarted which would appear as if nothing is wrong yet the response is incorrect.

Comment: but its happen only with zip file. i downloaded mp3 and other file every thing working fine but only with zip file its not working...

Comment: MIME type/Filetype filtering is the most probable culprit. can you download the same file directly through a browser?